# .net: In my build/Debug directory i find MyProjectName_Accessor.exe ? What is this?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winforms app and when i compile i get the EXE compiled but i also get

```
   MyProjectName_Accessor.exe
```

I understand why I have

```
   MyProjectName.exe
```

This is my executable but i don't understand where the other file is coming from.

If i try to execute it, it fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably [private accessor assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514191%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) used by mstest. When you generate unit tests using mstest, it creates private member accessor assembly for the assembly you are testing, so that you can test private members. This can happen if you choose "generate unit tests" in VS and select some private type.

Now this accessor assembly should belong to your test project, so I'm not sure how it happens to be next to your main exec.